# How to search by text in Java on Mongo db

Tags: java, mongodb

How can I write the equivalent of this query for Mongo DB in Java:

```
db.mydata.find({$where: "this.fields.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('ar') > 0"})
```

?

The query is used to find all names that include "AR" (martin, mark, etc.).

I am using `QueryBuilder` at the moment, but it doesn't support that kind of query format.

Any idea?

Comment: @Philipp That would be a duplicate if only it actually mentioned how to do it in JAVA

Comment: Realize that this is going to search every document in the collection if you don't use an anchored regex search (and have an indexed field). Slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An option is to use a Regex instead.

i.e.

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("ar",  Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
DBObject query = new DBObject("fields.name", regex);
Cursor result = myCollection.find(query);
```

Comment: you are the man! thank you! Just a little correction: new BasicDBObject("fields.name", regex);